# How do I read data in drop down?

Tags: vb.net

I can view the data in textbox but the problem is, if I change it to drop down to show multiple data, it will give an empty data ..

```
Private Sub textbox2_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress

    Try

        cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT maker FROM pcba_info.tblvendorpartnumber WHERE partnumber ='" & Trim(TextBox2.Text.TrimEnd()) & "'", con)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If dr.Read Then

 TextBox55.Text = dr("maker").ToString ----------> return single data


TextBox12.SelectedIndex = dr("maker").ToString -----------> no data

            dgvcertifiedoperator.DataSource = dt
            dgvcertifiedoperator.Update()
            dgvcertifiedoperator.Refresh()

        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine("Plz check the parts" & ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1349568.aspx

Comment: You have a SelectionChangeCommitted method being handled by a KeyPress event (without the KeyPressEventArgs) and a TextBox12 control which sounds like a TextBox but you are accessing a SelectedIndex property as if it was a ListBox.  That's some odd code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your `TextBox12` represents a dropdown. In this case assigning `SelectedIndex` to a string is incorrect (just think about it for a second - an index cannot be a string, i.e. `AAA` is not an index). Use `Option Strict On` to prevent such errors.

See, by default, VB.NET does not prevent you from doing it, because theoretically a string can be an integer, so this statement can work. But it does not mean it will work 100% of the time. `Option Strict` validates type conversion to ensure it always works, or your code does not compile.

Back to your question, one way to do it is to accumulate values in a list, then make that list a data source for your dropdown, like this:

```
Dim lst As New List(Of String)
While dr.Read Then
  lst.Add(dr("maker").ToString)
End While

TextBox12.DataSource = lst
```

You can then retrieve current value by using `TextBox12.SelectedItem`, cast to string:

```
DirectCast(TextBox12.SelectedItem, String)
```

A side note - make sure your controls are named accordingly. TextBox is usually reserved for, well, text boxes. Dropdowns are usually `MakerComboBox`, `MakerDropDown` etc. Avoid naming your controls like `TextBox56` and `ComboBox188`, because those numbers are meaningless for another developer. Even if you are the only one on the project, consider us helping you with it.